# how to receive result with span tag in my calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a calculator in JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/or0sexp1/

I want to edit this calculator so that when the <kbd>=</kbd> button is pressed the output is added to my `#history` div

I currently have the following `onclick` event on the <kbd>=</kbd> button:

```
$("#equal").click(function(){
    var str = $("#history").text();
    var re = /[0-9]+/g;
    var re2 = /[0-9]+(.)[0-9]+/;
    var operands = str.match(re);
    var Operation = str.match(re2)[1];
    var A = operands[0];
    var B = operands[1];
    var Result = operands[2];
});
```

I want the `#history` output to be wrapped in `<span>` elements.

For example, if the input is <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> I want the `#history` div to be updated like:

```
<span id="A">5</span>
<span id="Operation">-</span>
<span id="B">1</span>
<span>=</span>
<span id="Result">4</span>
```

My current output looks like this:

```
"5-1="
<span id="Result">4</span>
```

I'm trying to achieve this without using **REGEX**

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: I want to receive data with this tags in html. this is important for me :/ please tell me the answer

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I guess you want : `<span id="A">5</span><span id="Operation">-</span><span id="B">1</span>=</span id="Result">4</span>`. But with so little effort to ask a question, why should we take time to answer it?! And what should happen for: `5-1+6+3+7`? Becasue IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: jasonscript very very very big thank for edit my answer :*

Comment: @VateX I've updated your question, but you might have a better chance of an answer if you post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some changes to your code.

```
$("#equal").click(function() {
    str = $("#history1").text();

    var re = /[0-9]+/g;
    var re2 = /[0-9]+(.)[0-9]+/;
    var operands = str.match(re);
    var Operation = str.match(re2)[1];
    var A = operands[0];
    var B = operands[1];
    var Result = operands[2];
    $("#history").append('<span id="A">' + operands[0] + '</span><span id="Operation">' + Operation + '</span><span id="B">' + operands[1] + '</span>=<span id="Result">' + $("#bar").val() + '</span>');
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/or0sexp1/4/)

I have created a calculator with a much cleaner way.

```
var operators = [];
$(".numbers,.operators,.dot").click(function() {
    $("#bar").val($("#bar").val() + $(this).val());
});
$(".operators").click(function() {
    operators.push($(this).val());
});
$("#equal").click(function() {
    var resultString = $("#bar").val();
    for (i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
        var div = $("<div/>");
        var firstIndex = resultString.indexOf(operators[i]);
        div.append("<span class='number'>" + resultString.substring(0, firstIndex) + "</span>");
        div.append("<span class='operator'>" + operators[i] + "</span>");
        resultString = resultString.substring(firstIndex + 1);
        operators.splice(i, 1);
    }
    div.append("<span class='number'>" + resultString + "</span>");
    div.append("<span>=</span>");
    $("#bar").val(eval($("#bar").val()));
    div.append("<span class='result'>" + $("#bar").val() + "</span>");
    $("#history").append(div);
});
```

[**Fiddle without using regex**](https://jsfiddle.net/or0sexp1/11/)

Comment: The second operation repeats the same text for `<span id="A">` and `<span id="B">

Comment: ok but I didn't won't to use RegExp :/ please tell me code without RegExp